# Как запустить произвольное количество потоков?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, указатели

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая запускала был произвольное количество потоков на выполнение.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void thf() {
    static int n = 0;
    n += 1;
    cout << "threads " << n << endl;
    n -= 1;
    return;
}

int main() {
    const int thrn = 10;
    thread *func_thread = new thread[thrn];

    for(auto i = 0; i < thrn; i += 1) {
        func_thread[i].operator()(thf); //Здесь ошибка no member named 'operator()' in 'std::__1::thread'
    }

    for(auto i = 0; i < thrn; i += 1) {
        auto &x = func_thread[i];
        if(x.joinable()) {
            x.join();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

UPD: Вариант решения

```
thread **func_thread = new thread*[thrn];

for(auto i = 0; i < thrn; i += 1) {
    func_thread[i] = new thread(thf);
}
```

Comment: А текст ошибки как переводится?

Comment: Не реализован оператор(). Суть ошибки мне понятна. Неясно, как можно выйти из этой ситуации.

Comment: ок, отсекли самую частую проблему — люди не читают сообщения ошибок )

Comment: Вы, судя по всему, считали, что можно запустить поток, и потом «привязать» к нему код для выполнения. Это не так: когда вы запускаете поток, вы обязаны передать ему функцию, и не можете подменить её в процессе работы потока. Когда функция отработает, поток завершится.

Comment: @VladD Почти. Я думал, что создание объекта thread != запуск потока на выполнение.

Comment: @Nex: В C#, кстати, это так и есть: объект `Thread` нужно ещё запустить методом `.Start()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему бы не написать просто

```
      func_thread[i] = thread(thf);
```

см., например [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/)

Comment: А здесь не будет UB? Набросал код с самописным классом, вроде все деструкторы объектов, созданных в цикле, вызываются до выхода из цикла: http://ideone.com/CYqXqF

Comment: @Nex, не знаю. Впрочем, это не очень важно, поскольку кресты (из-за своей внутренней сложности) не тот язык, на котором стоит  писать серьезные вещи.